# FineUploader UI shows thumbnail on file select, but not drag-n-drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Using React and FineUploader 5.14.2-rc1 in UI mode. Uploads work great, but the displayed thumbnails are inconsistent. When I click the component and select a file from the system file selection dialog, the file is represented by a thumbnail of the image. But when I drag the same file and drop it on the component, it displays a generic file icon rather than an image thumbnail. I'm assuming this is a configuration problem, but I can't find anything germane in the documentation. Here's the relevant component:

```
import FineUploaderS3 from 'fine-uploader-wrappers/s3'
import Gallery from 'react-fine-uploader'

export default class FileUploader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            showModal: props.showModal || false,
            fileName: props.fileName,
            s3Key: props.s3Key,
            title: props.title,
            description: props.description,
            fileUrl: props.fileUrl,
            success: props.success || true,
        }

        let uploaderInstance = null

        this.uploader = () =>{
            uploaderInstance = new FineUploaderS3({
                options: {
                    chunking: {
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    resume: {
                        enabled: true 
                    },
                    request: {
                        endpoint: 'http://ourbucketurl',
                        accessKey: ourAccessKeyId,
                    },
                    signature: {
                        endpoint: '/api/s3handler', 
                    },
                    uploadSuccess: {
                        endpoint: '/api/s3uploadsuccess', 
                    },
                    callbacks: {
                        onComplete: this.uploadCompleteHandler
                    },
                }
            })

            return uploaderInstance
        }

        this.uploadCompleteHandler = (id, name, responseJSON) => {
            this.setState({showModal: responseJSON.success,
                s3Key: responseJSON.key,
                fileName: responseJSON.name,
                fileUrl: `https://ourbucketurl/${responseJSON.key}`})
        }

    render() {

        return <div>
            <Gallery uploader={this.uploader()} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

I can put this component anywhere, and files upload without incident.

The problem occurs regardless of browser. What do I need to do to show thumbnails consistently regardless of how the user invokes the upload operation?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code to support file dropping here, or a file input element, or a UI for that matter.

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the question to include more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this myself, downgraded to react-fine-uploader 0.6.0 and all works again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Have you noticed any undesirable side-effects from the downgrade?